# CUDA triple brackets optional parameters

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I know that a kernel may be launched with the triple brackets syntax:

```
kernel<<<NumOfBlocks, NumOfThreadsPerBlock, A, B>>> (...);
```

the last two parameters are optional but I'd like to know what do they refer to. B should refer to the stream where the kernel should be executed, but what about A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is amount of shared memory. You can pass as A number of bytes that you need in shared memory. And in kernel you should use

```
extern __shared__ T smem[];
```

instead of

```
__shared__ T[CONSTANT];
```

to get shared array with size A / sizeof(T) in your kernel.

Comment: The second optional parameter is the stream in which to launch the kernel.

Comment: Where is this documented? I can't seem to find it in the docs (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)